# Display objects that are LIKE another object that is being displayed on show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, methods, scopes

Hopefully the title makes some sense but I will go into more details. I have a simple app that allows users to upload recipes. You can then view them all or view each recipe individually via the show action

```
def show
@recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
end
```

In the view i then display various attributes for that recipe like so

```
  <b><%= @recipe.dish_name %></b><br>
  <b><%= image_tag @recipe.avatar.url(:showrecipe) %><b><br>
  <b>by&nbsp;<%= @recipe.user.name %></b></br></br>
  <b>Description</b></br>
  <b><%= @recipe.description %></b></br>
  <b>Ingredients</b></br>
  <b><%= raw(ingredient_names_list(@recipe.ingredients)) %></b>
  <br>
  <b>Preperation Steps</b></br>
  <ol>
  <li><%= raw(preperation_steps_list(@recipe.preperations)) %></li>
  </ol>
```

What I would like to achieve is to have a section on the same page that will list the names of other recipes that are LIKE the recipe being shown, based on dish_name

This is my first time doing something like this so i am looking for some pointers on what resources to look at or how i would go about this

My thinking so far is to

1) Create a method that calls a scope based on the dish_name being displayed, passing the params of the dish_name.

That may be wrong, just looking for a nudge in the right direction please

EDIT

I have also tried this in my show action but i get wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

```
@relatedrecipe = Recipe.where(@recipe.dish_name('LIKE'),(params[:dish_name]))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I were doing this, I would plug my app into a full-text search database, such as `sunspot_solr` with `sunspot_rails` and index the titles, description, and list of ingredients.

Then use a normalized version of the title and ingredients to create a generic search excluding the record you are already looking at to come up with near-hits and related content.

**Edit** for a more concrete example using `sunspot_rails` (something I have some experience with):

sunspot_rails uses a searchable block in your model to tell it what it should index on create/update/destroy.
You can create custom indexes like I show below with :ingredient_names.

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base

  searchable do
    integer :id
    string  :description
    text    :preparations
    text    :ingredient_names
  end

  def ingredient_names
    ingredients.map{|i| i.name }.uniq.compact.join(' ')
  end

  def similar_recipes
    search = Recipe.search do
      without(:id, self.id) # don't return the same record
      fulltext(self.description) do
        boost_fields(:description => 2) # give extra weight to description matches
      end
      fulltext(self.ingredient_names)
    end
    search.results
  end

end
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i have read though that it doesnt deal with associated models? is that right?

Comment: ah my mistake seems there is a method called multi_solr_search

Comment: would you mind giving me an example to get me started please? appreciate your help

Comment: @Richlewis Updated with an example. Check the docs here: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#readme